# Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: javascript, undefined, jslint

So jsLint says my x is not defined. I looked it up everywhere but I cant find how to define it...

```
for (x = 0; x < verdachten.length; x++) {
       console.log("De verdachte is de  " + verdachten[x].leeftijd + "jaar oud " + verdachten[x].naam  + ", de " + verdachten[x].wie);
    }
```

That's where it goes wrong. The x...

Comment: You mean like `var x;`?

Comment: You need `for (var x = 0; . . .`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of jsLint being a *bit* overcautious. Most browsers will automagically define the `x`, but jsLint warns of this as it's easy to get a scoping bug if you don't properly init your variables, like this:

```
for( var x = 0; x < verdachten.length; x++ ) {
  console.log(
    "De verdachte is de " +
    verdachten[x].leeftijd +
    "jaar oud " +
    verdachten[x].naam +
    ", de " +
    verdachten[x].wie
  );
}
```

Problems can arise if you have an `x` defined somewhere else within scope:

```
function doStuff() {
  var x = "derp";

  // things
  console.log(x); //=> "derp";

  for(x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // other things
    console.log(x);//=> 0..99
  }

  console.log(x); //=> 99
  // original x variable has now changed :(
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var x = 0; x < verdachten.length; x++) {
       console.log("De verdachte is de  " + verdachten[x].leeftijd + "jaar oud " + verdachten[x].naam  + ", de " + verdachten[x].wie);
    }
```

**for (var x = 0; x < verdachten.length; x++) {**

You have the problem in defining the variable 'x'. In javascript variables are defined by prefix var and do not require variable type.

Happy Programming :)